# Please assist in printing out the even numbers of the below program

Tags: java

```
public class MultiTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] lottogroups = {{1111,2222,3333,4444},{6666,7777,8888,9999},{11111,121212,131313}};
        for(int i = 0;i < lottogroups.length ;i++){
            System.out.println("Group :"+i);
            for(int j = 0;j < lottogroups[i].length ;j++){
                System.out.println("  Value "+j+" = "+lottogroups[i][j]);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You definetly need to explain a little bit more your problem. What is not going as you want, what you're expecting

Comment: How about trying by yourself? Then you could consult here your results, but you can't expect people doing work for you

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/2545439

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple trick to find out whether a number is even, etc.

The `%` operator helps to see whether a number is divisible by a certain number. Even number are divisible by 2.

```
if (lottogroups[i][j] % 2 == 0) // number is even
```